# Want to specify jar name and version both in build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I want to specify the jar name and version in build.gradle, so my build.gradle looks like below.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version = "1.00.00"

 dependencies { 
     compile files('../../lib/abc.jar') 
} 

jar{
    manifest{
        attributes ("Fw-Version" : "2.50.00", "${parent.manifestSectionName}")

    }
    archiveName 'abc.jar'
}
```

So when I do

**gradle clean build**,  what I was expecting was that the generated jar name would be abc-1.00.00.jar

But its not happening, the output jar name is getting as abc.jar only and its just ignoring the version. I want to specify both jar name and version, so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Read https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName and https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:baseName

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`archiveName 'abc.jar'` in your `jar` configuration is forcing the name to be 'abc.jar'. The default format for the jar name is `${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${classifier}.${extension}`, where `baseName` is the name of your project and `version` is the version of the project. If you remove the archiveName line in your configuration you'll have the format you're after. If you want the name of the archive to be different from the project name set the `baseName` instead, e.g.

```
jar {
    manifest{
        attributes ("Fw-Version" : "2.50.00", "${parent.manifestSectionName}")
    }
    baseName 'abc'
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName for more info on configuring the `jar` task.

Comment: In 5.2.1 (current version) the property `baseName` is [deprecated](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName), while the replacement [`archiveBaseName`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveBaseName) is read-only. How do we do that in next version of Gradle?

Comment: `archiveFileName`

Answer (score 38):

For **Gradle 5+**

`build.gradle` groovy DSL

```
archiveBaseName = 'foo'
```

`build.gradle.kts` kotlin DSL

```
archiveBaseName.set("foo") // Notice the double quotes
```

Comment: there's a typo, should be 'archivesBaseName'

Comment: @QuiltyKim Referring to the official docs, it's `archivesBaseName` with `s`.

Comment: `archivesBaseName` (with **s**) is a property in the Java plugin, not the Jar plugin. However the Jar plugin defaults to the value in `archivesBaseName` if `archiveBaseName` is not set.

Comment: Thanks for the Kotlin DSL hint.

Comment: `archivesbaseName` hasn't the `set` method

Comment: "> Could not set unknown property 'archiveBaseName' for project ':lib' of type org.gradle.api.Project." With the 's' it works.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to achieve this in Kotlin DSL and this was the first question that came up on Google for me. The answers that involved Kotlin DSL did not work but I managed to find a solution.

---

Create this in the `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
tasks.jar {
  manifest {
    [THE LINES BELOW WILL BE INSERTED HERE]
  }
}
```

---

***Assume that the project name is `project` and the project version is `1.0`.***

To change the base name of the jar file:

```
archiveBaseName.set("name") // .jar name: name-1.0.jar
```

To change the entire jar file name, write this instead:

```
archiveFileName.set("name.jar") // .jar name: name.jar
```

---

Use `${project.name}` and `${project.version}` to insert the project name and version respectively, e.g:

```
archiveFileName.set("${project.name}-${project.version}.jar") // .jar name: project-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the [doc of gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName),the baseName and archiveName is deprecated,you should use archivesBaseName in project level like this:

```
project(":web") {
    description = "web"
    archivesBaseName = "your-project-name-" + getVersionCode()

    jar {
        // Will include every single one of your dependencies, project or not
        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for my project. I hope it will be helpful for your project.

Answer (score 2):

For Gradle 6.x

Set the version to empty.

- version = ''
- project.archivesBaseName - It is the way.

More on their [DOC](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveBaseName)!

Answer (score 2):

**For Gradle 5.x, 6.x and 7.x**
(tested personally on Gradle 7.6 and verified the documentation of version 5)

In more recent versions of Gradle the results described by the OP are achieved automatically by the default building script if you specify the `version` property in your module `build.gradle` file (commonly seen right after your `plugin` block and before any other blocks).
So it would look something like this:

```
plugins {
    // your plugins...
}

// This is the string you want to have.
version = '1.0.0'

dependencies {
    // your dependencies
}
```

`version` accepts any string, so you can also append pre-release strings like `1.0.0-beta` if you need to.

However, one more thing to note is that by default Gradle uses the module name as the base name or your archives and jar files. If your module name matches the name of your library this shouldn't be a problem, but a common scenario it to work with sub-modules where you usually have a `lib` or `core` module, and in this case your jar file will end up being named something like `lib-1.0.0.jar`. To avoid this, you can specify the `archivesBaseName` property. You can put it right below (or above) your `version`:

```
version = '1.0.0'
archivesBaseName = 'abc'
```

This will correctly generate a `abc-1.0.0.jar` file. 
Note that `archivesBaseName` **uses the *plural*** `archives`, and it comes from the [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:archivesBaseName) type, and **NOT the *singular*** form `archive` that comes from the `jar` task.

But, if you need more granularity other than what described above, you will indeed need to use the [`jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) task, similarly to how the OP originally intended to.

Answer (score 1):

In `build.gradle.kts`, I was able to customize jar naming as follows:

```
tasks.jar {
    archiveFileName.set("application.jar")
}

tasks.bootJar {
    archiveFileName.set("application-plain.jar")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename the JAR, source JAR and javadoc JAR with a single setting, while still including the classifier and version, set `archiveBaseName` at the top level.

Comment: also a type here, should be 'archivesBaseName'

Comment: This is how it's listed in the gradle docs. Maybe submit an issue? https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveBaseName

Comment: So you never tested it?

Answer (score 0):

Add Apk base name in gradle

```
archivesBaseName = "appname-${new Date().format('dd-MM-yy-HHmm')}"
```

Gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    archivesBaseName = "appname-${new Date().format('dd-MM-yy-HHmm')}"
    resValue 'string', "authority", applicationId + ".fileprovider"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<pre><code>
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'


jar {
    archivesBaseName = archivesBaseName + '-' + version
}

</pre></code>
```

For me I just add above