# Gradle set name for jar created with spring-boot's assemble

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to create an executable jar with gradle (kotlin-dsl)  and I want to give it a custom name. For the executable jar I'm using the spring boot plugin and `./gradlew :app1:assemble`:

```
plugins {
    id("myproject.java-application-conventions")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
}
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":lib"))
}
application {
    mainClass.set("org.myproject.app.Main")
}
```

`init` created two more files, `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myproject.java-application-conventions.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("lomboker.java-common-conventions")
    application
}
```

With `./gradlew :app1:assemble` I can create an executable jar but I don't see how I can set its name.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405818/want-to-specify-jar-name-and-version-both-in-build-gradle) deals with naming jars but I don't know how to apply any answers to my problem.

Adding a `jar` block to my gradle file does not work: `Expression 'jar' cannot be invoked as a function.` it is interpreted as `sun.tools.jar.resources.jar`. So I try `tasks.jar` instead.
For

```
tasks.jar {
    archiveBaseName.set("myapp")
    archiveVersion.set("version")
}
```

`./gradlew :app1:jar` while building successful creates no jar (it wouldn't be executable anyway) and `./gradlew :app1:assemble` ignores the properties and just creates `./app1/build/libs/app1.jar`.

Since I'm not using `jar` but `assemble` I guess I should use a `tasks.assemble` block. But that doesn't recognize `archiveBaseName` or `archiveVersion` and I don't know what the API is.

This is the page: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot but I find no API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assemble` is a lifecycle task which means that it doesn’t create anything. Its role is to trigger other tasks that it depends upon and that do have some output. You can see those tasks by running your build with `--console=plain`.

The task that [creates the Spring Boot fat jar is named `bootJar`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.3/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-jars). As you can see from [its javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.3/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootJar.html), it’s a customization of Gradle’s `Jar` and can be configured in the same way:

```
tasks.bootJar {
    archiveBaseName.set("myapp")
    archiveVersion.set("version")
}
```